# Массив указателей на динамические массивы символов

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы, malloc

Нужно создать массив указателей на массивы символов. Символы вводятся пользователем, а массив символов заканчивается символом новой строки. Все пробелы и табуляции удаляются.

Код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 1024
#define ARR_SIZE 1024


int main ( void )
{
    char c;
    char string[SIZE];
    char *pmt;
    char *arr[ARR_SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int x;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        if ( c != ' ' && c != '\t' )
        {
            if ( c == '\n' )
            {
                string[i] = '\0';
                pmt = (char*) malloc(i + 1);
                if ( pmt == NULL )
                    exit(1);
                for (x = 0; x <= i; x++)
                    pmt[x] = string[x];
                arr[j] = pmt;
                i = 0;
                j += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                string[i] = c;
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= j; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    for(i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
    free(pmt);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Вывод правильный, но в конце выдает ошибку сегменирования:

```
abc  
d e f 
abc
def
Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
```

Comment: Подозреваю что тут проблема ```free(pmt);``` Разве pmt указывает не на один из ```arr[x]``` которые все были обнулены чуточку раньше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых у вас массив указателей `char * arr [ ARR_SIZE ] ;` содержит мусор памяти, и при удалении **всего** массива указателей происходит ошибка удаления памяти с неправильными адресами.
Цикл надо чуток укоротить до `i < j` , *строго меньше*:

```
for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
    free(arr[i]);
```

Во вторых, адрес `pmt` уже хранится в массиве `arr` и двойное удаление указателя приведёт опять к ошибке.
Убираем это :

```
// free(pmt);
```

И наконец правильные указатели хранятся по индексам `0` .. `j-1`, а вы выводите включительно, исправляем на `i < j` :

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
```

Comment: помоему еще это место упущено в ответе.... ```pmt = (char*) malloc(i + 1);``` эта память нигде не очищается, хотя должна быть очищена до окончания цикла ```while```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков `arr[j] = pmt; j += 1;` - а это ?

Comment: Да, это я проглядел,  выходит только лишняя очистка :)